# error: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this python code to read an image and convert it into a matrix of data, but I encounter the error above, and I hope you can help me in figuring out what is going one

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import array
import numpy as np



img = Image.open('felix.png')
arr = array(img)

im = Image.open("felix.png")
col,row =  im.size
data = np.zeros((row*col, 5))
pixels = im.load()
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        r,g,b =  pixels[i,j]
        data[i*col + j,:] = r,g,b,i,j




print (data)
```

the error, Value error: too many values to unpack is for this line: r,g,b =  pixels[i,j]

Thanks a a lot

Answer (score 5):

This error means that each pixel contains more than the 3 values you've provided variables for. It's reasonable to assume that these are actually RGBA pixels.

```
r,g,b,a = pixels[i,j]
```

This won't be the case for every PNG file you open, so you need to be able to deal with this situation dynamically.

Comment: thanks a lot, Can you elaborate please and help me what do you mean, Cause i'm completely new to python, and I just need to find the colors of each pixel and its x, y location.

Comment: @ali A PNG file can be one of 3 different pixel formats. It can be paletted, which means each pixel only has one value and you must use that as an index into the palette to get the true color. It can be RGB, which means each pixel has 3 values, one each for red, green, and blue. Or it can be RGBA with 4 values per pixel, the first 3 being the same as RGB and the fourth being an indication of how transparent the pixel should be, 0 for fully transparent or 255 for fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple images with different bands (RGB/RGBA) and you don't want to filter them then just do this:

```
band = pixels[i,j]
r = band[0]
g = band[1]
b = band[2]
```